# How to call webservices through selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, web-service, api-testing

I want to call the rest api in the selenium and save the JSON (response) in text file.

I also need to pass header value for webservice authentication.

Comment: What language are you using? Selenium is not designed for WebServices so you would need to consume the webservice using the language you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Why you wanted to use Selenium to call web-services? Selenium is not made for it. You can try few things using webdriver actually.

- Many have already used Java + selenium webdriver to call & interact with webservices. check here for [example](http://forumsqa.com/question/how-to-automate-web-servicesapis-using-selenium-webdriver/)